# ARGB Hex Colour To LibGdx Colour

Tags: android, libgdx

I am making a LibGdx application to be embedded as a Android Fragment.

I am having an issue with passing a Android colour resource to be used in LibGdx

This is my colour

```
<resources>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
</resources>
```

I pass this colour as follows

```
ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.red)
```

This returns an `int` which I convert to `float`

I have a texture which is a white circle that I colour as so

```
spriteCircle.setColor(myColor)
```

This calls upon the `Sprite` class `public void setColor (float color)`

The output is not red but a different color

Using one of the Color constants from LibGdx `com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color` yields the correct result so my texture can be coloured correctly so I can rule that out.

My theory is that Android colour has a different format from LibGdx

I wrote this method to help convert that

```
private com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color convertColorToLibGdxColor(int color) {
        float alpha = Color.alpha(color);
        float red = Color.red(color);
        float green = Color.green(color);
        float blue = Color.blue(color);
        return new com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color(red, green, blue, alpha);
    }
```

Note that the `Color.red` method comes from the `android.graphics.Color` class

```
 /**
     * Return the red component of a color int. This is the same as saying
     * (color >> 16) & 0xFF
     */
    public static int red(int color) {
        return (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
    }
```

There is a method for blue, green and alpha is well.

Then I call the `public void setColor (Color tint)` from the `Sprite` class

What is interesting, If I use a Color constant from Android `android.graphics.Color` such as

```
 @ColorInt public static final int RED         = 0xFFFF0000;
```

It works fine but not my colour resource I posted above

When I compared the two, I can see that my colour resource has the alpha channel omitted so I decided the fill that portion in so now it is

```
<resources>
    <color name="red">#FFFF0000</color>
</resources>
```

However, I still experience the same issue

Debugging the `ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.red)`
yields a value `0xFFD4172A`. I imagine the problem lies here

tl;dr Is it possible to translate a Android colour resource for use in LibGdx?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is actually a method for this in libgdx color class. 
https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Color.html#argb8888ToColor-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color-int-

It's also static method but instead of returning a new color, changing existing color.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @deniz-yılmaz

LibGdx already has a method for parsing ARGB colours

```
private com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color convertArgbToLibGdxColor(@ColorInt int argbColor) {
    com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color color = new com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color();
    com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color.argb8888ToColor(color, argbColor);
    return color;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a Gist which actually resolved my issue here 
https://gist.github.com/steen919/8a079f4dadf88d4197bb/d732449eb74321207b4b189a3bcbf47a83c5db65

```
public final class ArgbHexToLibGdxColor {

    private ArgbHexToLibGdxColor() {
    }

    /**
     * Taken from https://gist.github.com/steen919/8a079f4dadf88d4197bb/d732449eb74321207b4b189a3bcbf47a83c5db65
     * Converts the given hex color in 0xAARRGGBB format to a {@link Color} that can be used in a LibGdx application
     */
    public static Color convert(long hex) {
        float a = (hex & 0xFF000000L) >> 24;
        float r = (hex & 0xFF0000L) >> 16;
        float g = (hex & 0xFF00L) >> 8;
        float b = (hex & 0xFFL);
        return new Color(r / 255f, g / 255f, b / 255f, a / 255f);
    }

    /**
     * Converts a Android color resource into a {@link Color}  that can be used in a LibGdx application
     *
     * @see #convert(long)
     */
    public static Color convert(@NonNull Context context, @ColorRes int colorRes) {
        return convert(ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorRes));
    }
}
```

This seems to work with colours obtained from the colors.xml file and the constants from the Android Color class